# Word add-in js getHtml() function not return all fully style

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I write word add-in in JS using this API: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview

When I use function *body.getHtml()* I get almost everything , but some style is missing ,for example table of content is not with style, and when I use *body.insertHtml()* all style of table of content is not exist.

I success to get all style with *body.getOoxml()* function but it's very very long when I compare it to the html and this is bug problem for me .

What could I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when you create a TOC what really happens in the doc is that we insert a special type of content control wrapping the TOC and we don't roundtrip it in docx-html conversions. In  fact, if you save your TOCed document as HTML you will see that the style is lost in the resulting html. FWIW the links on the resulting HTML are functional.

That said, your only option as of now is to go OOXML. 
thx,
Juan.

Comment: It's happen just with TOC or with another types in word that lost their style ? And why OOXML is so big? the different is hugh , I check something simple for example and it was different of 40,000 characters or more... thx

Comment: Happens with other similar objects such as content controls.  Your second question might be challenging to answer in a stack comment but shorty it's  because a) the nature of ooxml and b)  because we are including the full ooxml package who can be useful in some scenarios. We wrote an article that you might find useful to learn this in way more detail https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md

Comment: Thx again , from reading this article I try to understand yet ... There is a way to replace all document with another document (OOXML) without replace all ooxml? I mean the function body.insertOOXML being very very slow and computer stuck when try to insert and the document is very big , so maybe there is some alternative for this ?